# Send a webhook request when a defined comment is received

Tags: git, github, webhooks

My question is simple: is there a way to activate a webhook only if the commit message received from the push is equal to a phrase we already defined.

Example: Let's say my message signal would be `"Launch me"`

if I do the following:

```
git commit -m "Imported Something"
git push origin master
```

then nothing will happen. But with:

```
git commit -m "Launch me"
git push origin master
```

then the webhook will get launched and send the signal to the address configured.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could actually use something called git hooks for rejecting the commit/push based on the commit-message phrase and based on that webhook will be triggered automatically if it is configured to be invoked for push events.
please refer to this link
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks